# CentOs - Tomcat - Angular2 - Encoding UTF-8

Tags: angular, tomcat, encoding, utf-8, centos

I have a SpringBoot Angular app deployed in a Tomcat which is in a CentOs server.

CentOs locale :

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

In the Tomcat's catalina.sh sript, I have the following config :

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding='UTF-8'"
```

In the index.html of the Angular app :

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

In the pom.xml of the parent project :

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEnc‌​oding>
```

All files are encoded in UTF-8

With all that some characters are not well displayed :

```
é -> Ã©
à -> Ã¨
° -> Â°
...
```

However, the characters from the database are well displayed (the database is encoded in ANSI)

Does anyone have an idea where is my mistake ?

Comment: Does Java web app build in UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, I have the following line in the pom.xml : <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

Comment: Does your source code file save in UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, all files are saved in UTF-8

Comment: Java business logic maybe cause encoding mismatch. Can you post source code to GitHub and share link?

Comment: Unfortunatly, I cannot do this, it's confidential. I'll try later to build a simple project with the same problem then publish to GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was resolved adding the charset to the js and html mime types into the tomcat's web.xml :

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>html</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html;charset=UTF-8</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>js</extension>  
    <mime-type>text/javascript;charset=utf-8</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>
```