# Incorrect display of special characters in browser - Angular i18n

Tags: angular, encoding, utf-8, internationalization, angular-i18n

I'm using Angular4 i18n support for my project to translate English to Spanish. My generated messages.xlf file is UTF-8 encoded.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`

And I have 2 other files with translated text as messages.en.xlf and messages.es.xlf. These two files also have UTF-8 encoding.

Angular project index.html also has UTF-8 encoding.

```
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Translated text in messages.es.xlf looks like this.

```
<trans-unit id="dashGeneric" datatype="html">
    <source>Generic</source>
    <target state="translated">Genérico</target>
    <context-group purpose="location">
      <context context-type="sourcefile">product.component.d.ts</context>
      <context context-type="linenumber">66</context>
    </context-group>
    <note priority="1" from="description">product- generic</note>
  </trans-unit>
```

Translated text display in browser as **GenÃ©rico**. But it should be **Genérico** as in messages.es file.

I opened the messages files in notepad++ and made sure they are encoded in UTF-8. But still no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that by setting mime types to charset=UTF-8 in tomcat server web.xml file.

[Link to the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44941055/4165181)

Answer (score 0):

```html
Add charset="UTF-8" to script tags which you are using to include the generated js files.

<script type="text/javascript" src=" source path " charset="UTF-8">

eg:
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
Note : Like the above example, add charset="UTF-8" for all the js files which you want to include
```

Comment: Problem is I don't include generated files to index.html. It is done by angulr-cli, isn't it?